# Approach to display links by role

Tags: algorithm, performance, hyperlink, roles, dry

Imagine you have a navbar with over 50 links (including dropdowns), and there are about 7 user roles within the app. I won't focus on any specific programming language, but rather on the most efficient algorithm to address this problem.

**The first approach** is the basic one, simply using a conditional statement to display or hide a link depending on the user's role. However, the issue here lies in the necessity to implement numerous conditional checks. For example, if roles #1, #5, and #7 have access to the "orders" link, you would need a conditional that checks for each link:

```
if user.role == 'role#1' || user.role == 'role#5' || user.role == 'role#7'
  link_to 'orders'
```

**The second approach** is to check the user's role just once. This lets you display the right links, but the code might become lengthy and hard to understand. It also wouldn't be easy to add new roles in the future.

```
if user.role == 'role#1'
  link_to 'orders'
  link_to 'products'
  link_to 'stores'
```

**The third approach** would be to implement a method using a hash or map, where the name of each link is a key, and the value is an array containing the roles authorized to access it.

```
navbar_link = {
  home: %i[super_admin admin warehouse_manager user],
  orders: %i[admin warehouse_manager user],
  view_orders: %i[admin warehouse_manager user],
```

**The fourth approach** would involve creating a method that iterates over the various options based on the role and returns an array with the links enabled for that role.

```
links = []

if user.admin?
  links.push(link_to("orders")
  links.push(link_to("products")
```

I've looked for similar questions but couldn't find any that propose a more efficient algorithm. If someone kind-hearted could share a bit of their experience, I would be very grateful.

Thanks.